# Compacting VHDX containing LUKS encrypted partition

Tags: linux, hyper-v, luks, vhd, vhdx

I simply cannot convince my VHDX to compact. It's the boot drive for a Ubuntu VM in Hyper-V, and the system partition is encrypted with LUKS.

What I've tried is attaching the VHDX to an entirely new VM, then

```
cryptsetup luksOpen --allow-discards /dev/sdb3 ubuntu_disk
```

to enable trimming (and the associated security imperfections).

This lets `fstrim` run without errors, but it doesn't seem to be enough to actually release the sectors so the VHDX compact process can shrink the file.

I've tried every which way to compact, via Hyper-V Management Console, PowerShell `Optimise-VHD -Mode Full`, `diskpart`, and it just seems like the trim never happened. Even when I `dd` a few GB of zeroes, `sync`, and `rm` the zeroes, nothing changed.

Any ideas how to compact this VHDX?